# float left right bottom

Tags: html, css

I set the parent div to relative, and the others to absolute and 50% width, but even jsfiddle shows that it's not working. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/kagawa_leah/3gcV9/1/

html:

```
    <div class="border">
        <div class="left">
            <p>LEFT Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div> <!--end left-->
        <div class="right">
           <p> RIGHT Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div> <!--end right-->
    </div> <!--end border -->
```

css:

```
.border {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
background-color: #000000;
}

.left {position: absolute; 
width: 50%; 
float:left; 
text-align:left; 
bottom: 4px; 
background-color:red; 
}

.right {position: absolute; 
width: 50%; 
float:right; text-align:right; 
bottom: 4px; 
background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t float absolute positioned elements. You probably just want to set `right/left` on each element. Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ByVGf/1/

```
.border {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
background-color: #000000;
}

.left {position: absolute; 
width: 50%; 
left: 0
text-align:left; 
bottom: 4px; 
background-color:red; 
}

.right {position: absolute; 
width: 50%;
right: 0;
text-align:right; 
bottom: 4px; 
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! thank you so much~ I guess I was making it too complicated. Can you tell me why the `right:0` pushes it to the edge (so that I will know for future reference)? I noticed that without it, the two divs "floated" left and right, but took up only the left 50%.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that You want to have two divs that split the parent in equal halves.

```
.border {

position: relative;
height: 100px;
background-color: #000000;
}

.sth {
width: 50%; 
float:left; 
text-align:left; 
bottom: 4px; 
background-color:red; 
}




 <div class="border">
        <div class="sth">
            <p>LEFT Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div> <!--end left-->
        <div class="sth">
           <p> RIGHT Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div> <!--end right-->
    </div> <!--end border -->
```

this is how it looks
http://jsfiddle.net/b2pC3/